# How to solve the following DE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$y \ dy = \big(-x + \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ \big)dx  $$ where y and x are variables.

I have tried dividing through by x, so then I can use the substitution $z =y/x$ however that doesn't lead me anywhere. I then tried to find an integrating factor however I don't seem to be able to.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint;
$$y \ dy = \big(-x + \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ \big)dx$$
$$\dfrac 12  dy^2+\dfrac12 dx^2 = \big( \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ \big)dx$$
$$\dfrac 12  d(y^2+ x^2) = \big( \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ \big)dx$$
Then the ODE is separable.

Comment: Oh wow that's smart. I sort of tried to do that at one point but didn't think much of it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @jambajuice .

Answer (score 1):

Just to show that your method does lead somewhere:

After making your substitution, I get $$\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+z^2} -(1+z^2)} dz = \frac{dx}{x} $$ Let’s look at the the integral of the left. Substitute $1+z^2 = t \implies 2zdz=dt $. $$\frac 12 \int \frac{dt}{\sqrt t -t}\\ =\int \frac{dt}{2\sqrt t(1-\sqrt t)} \\ =-\ln(1-\sqrt t) + c\\ =-\ln(1-\sqrt{1+z^2}) +c$$ Therefore the solution is $$x(1-\sqrt{1+z^2}) = C $$ or $$y^2 =C^2 -2Cx $$